# Show three datatable horizontal in stimul report

Tags: report, stimulsoft

I am using stimulsoft report, and I want to show three datatable next to each other, but when I add a table to page it fixes the whole width of page and the next table goes to the bottom. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

it depend on what you want to do if you have 3 independent datatable  you can use 3 panel in your report but if they are related datatables you should make a class like this

```
public class MainDatatable
{
    public List<Detail> DataTableList1 { get; set; }
    public List<Detail> DataTableList2 { get; set; }
    public List<Detail> DataTableList3 { get; set; }
}

public class Detail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }

}
```

and in your report you should make your business Object Category MainDatatable with 3 child business object and put one DataBind set the DatSource on MainDatatable , after that put 3 subreport on databind , in each page of subreport's put Databind and set The data source and master component each of them should be parent data bind